# IIS 7.5 Recycling App Pool at scheduled time

Tags: .net, iis, pool

we are experiencing an issue with application pools not recycling at the time they have been designated (could be because they have been shutdown, this is part of the question).  We have about 20 app pools running mainly .net 4 mvc sites and wcf service.  All app pools have been configured to recycle at the same specific time, and have been configured to log just such an event.  Upon checking the event viewer only 2 or 3 had actually recycled at all.  The problem seems to be manifesting itself by the applications then behaving in sometimes curious ways.

Does an application pool being shut down constitute a recycling of the application pool, upon restarting the worker process?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2 cents worth -

If you are referring to shutdown, the answer is no.

If you are referring to recycling the application pool by itself, the process creates a new worker before killing the old one, so there is no down time.

Upon starting up after shutdown, the worker processes will be newly initiated processes.

So, as there is a down time, I wouldn't say shutdown and restart constitutes a recycling process.

Hope that clarifies.